# ASUS TUF Dash F15 keyboard backlight not working

Tags: asus, brightness, backlight, keyboard-backlight

My keyboard backlight on my asus TUF dash F15 notebook does not work, even though I looked in `/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight` and brightness file changes on `Fn+F2` and `Fn+F3`.

I have tried some solutions I found here on askubuntu, for example:

- Changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub
- brightnessctl which succesfully detects asus::kbd_backlight and shows me that it is on 100%
- tools like `xset` and `xbacklight`

could this be a hardware problem?